# KL Divergence between the sums of random variables.

Tags: probability, information-theory

The relative entropy or Kullback–Leibler distance between
two probability density functions $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ is defined as
$$D(g\|f) = \int_{x} g(x)\log\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}  dx .$$
We have two random variables $V$ and $W$, 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
&V=X_1+X_2, \text{where}\ X_1\sim g(x), X_2\sim f(x)\ \text{are independent},\\
&W=X_3+X_4, \text{where}\ X_3, X_4\sim f(x)\ \text{are independent}.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
It is easy to show that 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
&V\sim G(x)=(g\ast f)(x),\\
&W\sim F(x)=(f\ast f)(x),
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
where $(g\ast f)(x) = \int g(\tau)f(x-\tau)d\tau$ is the convolution of $g$ and $f$.

The questions are:

1. Is it true that $D(g\|f)> D(G\|F)?$
2. Is it true that $\frac{1}{2}D(g\|f)> D(G\|F)?$

If we can prove 2, 1 is obviously true. 
They are true for Poisson and Gaussian distributions, however, I can't prove for the general cases.

Comment: Cool question. Intuitively speaking, any convolution should bring the pdf closer to a Gaussian (by the CLT) so this almost needs to be true. Will see if I have time to prove it.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, intuitively the question 1 is true. Since the relative difference between $g\ast f$ and $f\ast f$ is intuitively closer than the distance between $g$ and $f$. However, it is quite hard to prove without knowing the explicit forms of $g$ and $f$.

Comment: Hi, any headway with this question? Personally, I used that $D\left([V|X_2,X_4]\middle|\middle| [W|X_2,X_4]\right)=D\left([V|X_2]\middle|\middle| [W|X_4]\right)\geq D(V||W)$. But $D\left([V|X_2]\middle|\middle| [W|X_4]\right)=D(g||f)$ need not be the case, I think. With some abuse of notation, I take $[A|B]$ to be the distribution of $A$ given $B$.

Comment: similar questions have been asked before (on mathoverflow at least): see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/323030/kl-divergence-and-convolution-of-distributions) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272457/kl-divergence-convolution-of-distributions).

Comment: Do you assume that the pair $(X_1,X_2)$ is independent of $(X_3,X_4)$?

Answer (score 2):

I will reason in the domain of discret probabilities. As discret distributions are limits of continuous ones, I think we can prove that the result are valid in the domain of continuous densities.

**Proof of 1**

N.B strict inequality is false. Equality is evident when f=g

We note $g_i$ and $f_i$ the probabilities of g and f and $h_{ij}$ the conditional probabilities of $P(V / X_1)$

We just need the fact that V and W have the same conditional probabilities :

$P(V / X_1)=P(W / X_3)$

$$D(G \parallel F)=\sum_i{(\sum_j{g_jh_{ij}})}\log(\frac{\sum_k{}g_kh_{ik}}{\sum_k{}f_kh_{ik}})$$

We then use the Log-sum Inequality (cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_sum_inequality)

$$\log(\frac{\sum_k{}g_kh_{ik}}{\sum_k{}f_kh_{ik}}) \le \frac{\sum_k{g_kh_{ik}\log(\frac{g_k}{f_k})}}{\sum_k{g_kh_{ik}}}$$

So

$$D(G \parallel F)\le \sum_{i,k}g_kh_{ik}\log(\frac{g_k}{f_k})=\sum_k[g_k\log(\frac{g_k}{f_k})(\sum_ih_{ik})]=\sum_kg_k\log(\frac{g_k}{f_k})=D(g\parallel f)$$

**Counter exemple showing that 2 is not true**

Suppose Bernouilli distributions for each $X_i$ :

$P_f(X=0)=1-\epsilon$

$P_f(X=1)=\epsilon$

and the opposite for g :

$P_g(X=0)=\epsilon$

$P_g(X=1)=1-\epsilon$

We have :

$P_G(V=0)=P_G(V=2)=\epsilon-\epsilon^2$

$P_G(V=1)=1-2\epsilon+2\epsilon^2$

$P_F(W=0)=1-2\epsilon+\epsilon^2$

$P_F(W=1)=2\epsilon-2\epsilon^2$

$P_F(W=2)=\epsilon^2$

It is easy to show that for small $\epsilon$ :

$D(g \parallel f) \sim -\log(\epsilon)$ and $D(G \parallel F) \sim -\log(\epsilon)$

So $D(g \parallel f) \sim D(G \parallel F)$

Therefore, one can find an epsilon so that $\frac 1 2 D(g \parallel f) < D(G \parallel F)$

Answer (score 0):

The first inequality is a simple consequence of the chain rule for KL divergences with an additive noise "channel" where $X_2$ (or $X_4$) acts as noise.